# Recurrence relation with shifting arguments

Tags: r, recurrence

I have some problems with recurrence relation.
I have some data, `test_vec <- 1:5`, and a function of this data,
`F <- function(test_vec){
  2 * (test_vec + 3) + 3 * (test_vec + 4)
}`
I want to write a code that will iteratively perform the following steps:

1st iteration:

`2 * (test_vec + 3) + 3 * (test_vec + 4)`

2d iteration:

`2 * (2 * (test_vec + 3 - 1) + 3 * (test_vec + 4 - 1)) + 3 * (2 * (test_vec + 3 - 2) + 3 * (test_vec + 4 - 2))`

3d iteration:

`2 * (2 * (2 * (test_vec + 3 - 1 - 1) + 3 * (test_vec + 4 - 1 - 1)) + 3 * (2 * (test_vec + 3 - 2 - 1) + 3 * (test_vec + 4 - 2 - 1))) + 3 * (2 * (2 * (test_vec + 3 - 1 - 2) + 3 * (test_vec + 4 - 1 - 2)) + 3 * (2 * (test_vec + 3 - 2 - 2) + 3 * (test_vec + 4 - 2 - 2)))`

and so on. Meaning that, each time there is a multiplication by 2, it takes the result of the previous step and counts the same of `(test_vec - 1)`, when there is a multiplication by 3, it takes the result of the previous step and counts the same of `(test_vec - 2)`, and then it sums these two results.

For these examples, the results are `23 28 33 38 43`, `75 100 125 150 175` and `175 300 425 550 675` respectively.

I've written the following code:

```
test_vec <- 1:5

F <- function(test_vec){
2 * (test_vec + 3) + 3 * (test_vec + 4)
}`
`shift_F <- function(F, val){
function(test_vec){
test_vec - val
  }
}
test_rec <- function(l){
if (l == 1) {
return(F(test_vec))
  }
  else {
    return(2 * shift_F(test_rec(l - 1), 1)(test_vec) + 3 *
shift_F(test_rec(l - 1), 2)(test_vec))
  }
}
```

which leads to wrong and identical results for `l > 1`, namely, it returns `-3  2  7 12 17`.

What should be corrected or, if this logic is inapplicable to this problem, how should it be solved?

Comment: Is it `rapply()` what you're looking for?

Comment: @rmagno, probably yes, but how should it be applied in this case?

Comment: your example is hard to follow... can you provide a more abstract and mathematical description of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @rmagno, basically, I want to write a function that would shift an argument of another function by some parameter additionally to the shift that has already been performed.
Let F = 2f(x+3) + 3f(x+4), F(-a) = 2f(x+3-a)+3f(x+4-a), then:
step 1: S = 2F(-1) + 3F(-2) = 2(2f(x+3-1) + 3f(x+4-1)) + 3(2f(x+3-2) + 3f(x+4-2))
step 2: 2S(-1) + 3S(-2) = 2(2(2f(x+3-1-1) + 3f(x+4-1-1)) + 3(2f(x+3-2-1-2) + 3f(x+4-2-1-2))) + 3(2(2f(x+3-1-2) + 3f(x+4-1-2)) + 3(2f(x+3-2-2) + 3f(x+4-2-2)))
and so on
so I need to shift an argument of all functions in a sum by 1 or by 2, on the next step by 1 or by 2 again...